# Memory/CPU optimzation?

Tags: memory, cpu, primes

My program uses alot of memory and Processing power, I can only search up to 6000, is there any way to reduce the amount of memory this uses? This will really help with future programming endevours as it will be nice to know how to work with memory smartly.

```
    ArrayList<Integer> factor = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> non = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> prime = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter how high we want to search");
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    int max = sc.nextInt();
    int number = 2; 

while (number < max)
{

        for (int i=0;i<prime.size();i++)
    {
            int value = prime.get(i);
            if (number % value == 0)
        {
            factor.add(value);
        }
        else
        {
            non.add(value);
        }
    }

    if(factor.isEmpty())
    {   
        prime.add(number);
    }
    else
    {   
        composite.add(number);          
    }
    factor.clear(); 
    number++;


}   
    int howMany=prime.size();
    System.out.printf("The are "+howMany+" prime numbers up to " +max + " and they are: "  +prime );
    System.out.println();

}
```

Comment: What programming language is this? Is it Java? Please tag your question with the language in use. To update your question, click on the **"[edit]"** link under the post. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You do not say what language you are using, so this answer will be general.

To store primes up to 6,000 you only need about 3,000 bits which is less than 380 bytes.  Your basic solution is the Sieve of Eratosthenes and the fact that 2 is the only even prime.  You set up the sieve to handle only odd numbers, which halves the storage needed.  Since the sieve only holds prime or not prime for each odd number, the storage can be reduced to a single bit for each number.

Once you have set up your sieve, there are many sites including this one which have instructions in different languages, you just need to retrieve the prime/not prime value from the sieve for the numbers in your range.  Here is the pseudocode for checking if a number is prime, assuming the sieve has already been set up:

```
boolean function isPrime(number)

  // Low numbers
  if (number < 2)
    return false
  endif

  // Even numbers
  if (number is even)
    return number == 2
  endif

  // Odd numbers >= 3
  return sieve[(number - 1) / 2] == 1

end function
```

Low numbers are not prime.  2 is the only even prime; all other even numbers are not prime.  The prime flag for the odd number 2n+1 is stored at bit n in the sieve.  This assumes that the language you are using allows bit level access, something like a `BitSet` in Java.